How to send media file to flow http endpoint in firebase genkit?
Firebase Genkit let's you create "flows". Flows can be a complete replacement to an express server.
It is possible to call models inside flows using the generate function. The Genkit UI shows an option to upload media. But in production how would I send a media file to the flow? Do I always require to upload the file to a storage first and then pass on the url or I can upload it directly?

You can provide the image input to the flow either by passing it in directly or saving to storage first and passing the URL.  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/genkit/models#how_to_generate_content for example loading from a file and base64 encoding to pass an image as a string or passing as a URL.
